# MongoDB - A very Simple query is taking high response time

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

We have an issue with MongoDB query performance. There is a collection in MongoDb with approx 30 properties and total documents are near to 2000. Below is an example with one collection "deal", facing similar issue with almost all the collections in my db. Please note that i have created indexes, even compound indexes based on query use cases, and there is no COLLSCAN determined in any of the query. I have tried this with MongoDb 3.6 as well as 4.x, the result is same.

```
db.getCollection("deals").find({isActive:true, branch: ObjectId("5af1de276fcd080007ed79fd")})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQIrv.png)

Comment: So you have an index on `branch` and/or `isActive`? And how long does it take? For only 2000 documents, it should not take long even with no index at.

Comment: How many documents are returned from this query?

Comment: Yes, both are having index. It is returning around 5-6 documents respective to given branch.